# d3js pinch zoom issue on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, d3.js, ionic2

I am having a weird issue in regards to `d3 zoom` on `iPad` which is driving me mad. I am working on a `hybrid iPad app` using `Ionic` 2 as a base framework and the app incorporates an isometric city builder (similar to Clash of Clans but not as complicated) module.

I have utilized the features provided by d3 zoom to build the module.

But the **issue** is on `iPad`:

The `pinch zoom gesture` seems to be really sluggish when you place two fingers at the same time on the screen. Sometimes it seems to work relatively fine and the other time for some reason it simply doesn't. Weirdly if you place one finger after another on the screen, the gesture seems work absolutely fine!

I have tested the issue on `Android devices` and on the platform the issue doesn't seem to exist. It would be really helpful if some of you fine folks would help me out with this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: d3 version: 4.1.1

Comment: d3-zoom: 1.0.2
Ionic Framework: 2.0.0 rc.4

Comment: Are you sure you have the [proper meta tag](http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/starting.html) in place to disable native scaling?

Comment: Yes. I can confirm that the meta tag provided by the Ionic Framework is in place.